# Get only those array values which are repeating N number of times in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, arraylist, filter

I am trying to get those values from array which are repeating N number of times in array. I know it sounds confusing. Let me give an example:

I have an array as $filter:

```
array[
  0 => "556878",
  1 => "12345",
  2 => "12345",
  3 => "234567",
  4 => "45673",
  5 => "45673"
]
```

If you can see that **12345** is repeating **2 times**. Same is the case with **45673**.

I want to create a function or if exists already in PHP, that helps me to get only those values which are repeating N number of times. Like from the example above, value 12345 and 45673 is repeating 2 times. So If I give 2 as a parameter to a function like:

```
getNtimes($filter,2)
```

Its going to return:

```
array[
      0 => "12345",
      1 => "45673"
    ]
```

I am in search of most efficient way to get the desire results. Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply run the loop and saved values in another array and returned them :/

Comment: I'm flattered that you picked my answer but Alives answer is more efficient and faster even if it appears longer. My code does "three" loops, his does only two.

Comment: Well its strange that your answer is working much faster for me :P. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I can see that happening on smaller arrays perhaps but once you start loading the two functions I'm quite sure Alives answer will be faster. Or did you test them in the same file one after the other? That can make a difference too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_count_values()` with `foreach()` inside a function:-

```
function getNtimes($array,$count){
    $finalArray = [];

    $repeatedValuesCountArray = array_count_values($array);
    foreach($repeatedValuesCountArray as $key=>$value){
        if($value == $count){
            $finalArray[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $finalArray;
}


print_r(getNtimes($array,2));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/g846e

Comment: This is the fastest and most efficient way I can think of. I can't find a way that does only one loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your function using array_filter,

```
function getNtimes($arr, $n)
{
    $temp = array_count_values($arr);
    // filter with count and then get those keys.
    return array_keys(array_filter($temp, function ($value) use (&$n) {
        return $value == $n;
    }));
}
```

[array_keys](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) — Counts all the values of an array
[array_filter](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/02aTb).

Comment: Result is not the same as OP expects.

Comment: Yes, Result is different then I have expected.

Comment: @u_mulder Now check.

Comment: @FaranKhan You can check now.

Answer (score 2):

As others has answered, start with array_count_values.
Then I use array_intersect to get the values matching `$n`.
Lastly since the "values" are keys, I use array_keys to get the duplicated values from original array.

```
$n = 2;
$result = array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values($arr), [$n]));

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(12345)
  [1]=>
  int(45673)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/BIgCD

Answer (score 0):

Use array_unique() + array_filter() + array_count_values() :

```
print_r
  (
    array_unique(
      array_filter($arr = [
                            0 => 556878,
                            1 => 12345,
                            2 => 12345,
                            3 => 234567,
                            4 => 45673,
                            5 => 45673,
                          ], 
                    function ($v) use($arr) {
                      return array_count_values($arr)[$v] == 2;
                    }
                  )
    )
  );
```

If you need to re-index elements from 0 - apply array_values() to array_unique() result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` with `array_count_values`

```
$arr = [
  0 => "556878",
  1 => "12345",
  2 => "12345",
  3 => "234567",
  4 => "45673",
  5 => "45673"
];
$N = 2;
$final_result = array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function($v) use($N){
  return  $v==$N;
});
print_r($final_result);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
 [12345] => 2
 [45673] => 2
)
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/E05of)